# UnicodeEncodeError disparity between code run via django test suite vs django URL

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-unicode

Specifically I'm using the `webob` library where I posted a similar issue (https://github.com/Pylons/webob/issues/320), since I'm not sure if it's my usage, or a bug / documentation issue

Take the following code:

```
from webob.request import BaseRequest
req = BaseRequest.blank('http://example.com/%D0%B4%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B9%D1%82')
print req.environ['PATH_INFO']
print req.path
```

If I run this via a django shell, I get:

```
>>> req = BaseRequest.blank('http://example.com/%D0%B4%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B9%D1%82')
>>> print req.environ['PATH_INFO']
/дэльэнйт
>>> print req.path
/%D0%B4%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8D%D0%BD%D0%B9%D1%82
```

Where as running it as part of a Django test case I get the following from the first print:

```
/Ð´ÑÐ»ÑÑÐ½Ð¹Ñ
```

Followed by the exception:

```
File "/code/frontend/tests/test_views.py", line 55, in test_event
    print req.path
File "/virtualenv/frontend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 485, in path
    bpath = bytes_(self.path_info, self.url_encoding)
File "/virtualenv/frontend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/descriptors.py", line 68, in fget
    return req.encget(key, encattr=encattr)
File "/virtualenv/frontend/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 175, in encget
    return val.decode(encoding)
File "/virtualenv/frontend/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I get that this is probably some weird configuration with my test suite, however both run via the same method in the same environment (Django's `manage.py test` vs `manage.py shell`) and so I'm struggling to identify what's different. We're also running a ton of other unicode related tests without issue.

Thanks for any light shed on this.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this error in my local environment using:

 - python interactive shell
 - django interactive shell
 - django tests

All of those went fine. Do you have any test specific configuration related to encoding? Are you running all of these cases in the same terminal?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, It was pointed out elsewhere that I was importing `__future__.unicode_literals` which is true, and removing that fixes the issue described in this post, although this post actually drills down to a dependency of django webtest, so my overall problem isn't really solved. I think webtest itself might be encoding things in a way I'm not expecting. I might close this issue and open one better matching the scope of the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. use logging instead of print it's a best practice in all (not only Django) applications.
2. Or use req.path.decode('utf-8')